# Flicker when drawing to form with GDI

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, gdi

I'm making a Pong game in windows forms right now and the way that I'm rendering the graphics is by drawing to a bitmap every 100 ms from a task and then invalidating the form to force it to repaint the bitmap, it's working as intended except that the the form will "flicker" each time that I am repainting the bitmap, is there a way to not make it flicker like this?

Here is the code:

```
void IGameView.Draw(Ball ball, Paddle paddle, Paddle paddle2)
{
        //Draw to bitmap
        Graphics gameObj = Graphics.FromImage(gameObjects);
        BackColor = Color.Black; // Clear area to allow redrawing of all game objects
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.White, 5);
        gameObj.DrawEllipse(pen, new Rectangle(ball.Point, new Size(10, 10))); // Ball
        gameObj.DrawLine(pen, new Point(Size.Width / 2, 0), new Point(Size.Width / 2, Size.Height)); // Net
        gameObj.DrawLine(pen, paddle.Position, new Point(paddle.Position.X, paddle.Position.Y + paddle.Size.Height));
        gameObj.DrawLine(pen, paddle2.Position, new Point(paddle2.Position.X, paddle2.Position.Y + paddle2.Size.Height));
        pen.Dispose();
        gameObj.Dispose();
        Invalidate(); // Invalidate to force redraw of game objects
}

private void GameForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
        using (Graphics graphics = e.Graphics)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => GameForm_Paint(this, e)));
            } 
            else
            {
                graphics.DrawImage(gameObjects, new Point(0, 0));
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Try set the form's DoubleBuffered property to true

Comment: Few things here, first of all: Paint event won't ever be called in another thread (no check for InvokeRequired is needed). Second you create resources (pens and images) each time you draw. It's slow and, because you don't even dispose them, it wastes resources. Graphics.Clear() is terribly slow. Use control background (and move paint logic into IGameView.Draw but from a context received in PaintEventArgs). Finally you'll make it better using **double buffering** but only **after you fixed all of these**.

Comment: If you still have some flickering issues after setting DoubleBuffered property, you can override CreateParams in you main form. See [this](http://www.angryhacker.com/blog/archive/2010/07/21/how-to-get-rid-of-flicker-on-windows-forms-applications.aspx)

Comment: Interestingly enough when I set DoubleBuffered to true, the application will throw an exception at `Application.Run(new GameForm())` so basically before the form is created.

Comment: Really...double buffering here is the last thing you have to do (of course you have to do it but there are other more important issues). BTW drawing to an image is a kind of home made double buffering (but you should swap old/new after painting).

Comment: @Adriano Sorry I don't think I made it so clear, I've made sure to `Dispose` of the pen and graphics after I've used them and changed `Graphics.Clear` to `BackColor.set` and it is running with minimal flicker now :).

Comment: @Adriano "(and move paint logic into IGameView.Draw but from a context received in PaintEventArgs)". I didn't understand this part, are you saying that I should pass the `PaintEventArgs` as a parameter to `IGameView.Draw()` and then paint from there`?

Comment: Don't just call Dispose(), **reuse resources** (to create a brush/pen is an expansive operation). Yes, if you enable double buffering you don't need to paint into an image (and then paint image into context). Directly delegate painting to IGaveView.Draw() into final context.

Comment: Right I got DoubleBuffer to work now, apparently when using DoubleBuffer you are not supposed to Dispose of the drawing surface... Weird!